# How to use OutputStreams with chunked response in Play 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework, outputstream, loops

I need to use to `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream` to respond with a compressed file archive.

The data is several hundred megabytes uncompressed, so I would like to store as little of it as possible. It is coming from a serialization of SQL results.

I see examples of using an `OutputStream` to return a chunked result using `Enumerator.outputStream`:

- http://greweb.me/2012/11/play-framework-enumerator-outputstream/
- [Play/Akka integration with Java OutputStreams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065424/play-akka-integration-with-java-outputstreams)

but those seem ill-advised when I read the documentation (emphasis mine)

> Create an Enumerator of bytes with an OutputStream.
>
> Not that calls to write will not block, so if the iteratee that is being fed to is slow to consume the input, the
>   OutputStream will not push back.  This means **it should not be used with large streams since there is a risk of
>   running out of memory**.

Clearly, I can't use that. Or at least not without modification.

---

How can I create a response with an `OutputStream` (in this case, a gzipped archive) while being assured that only portions of it will be stored in memory?

I recognize the difference between `InputStream`s/`OutputStream`s and Play's `Enumerator`/`Iteratee` paradigm, so I expect there will be a specific way in which I need to generate my source data (serialization of SQL results) so that it doesn't outpace the rate of download. I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can't safely use any `OutputStream` with the Enumerator/Iteratee framework because `OutputStream` doesn't support non-blocking pushback. However, if you can control the writing to the `OutputStream` you can hack together something like:

```
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)

val enumerator = Enumerator.generateM {
  Future.successful {
    if (moreDateToWrite) {
      // Write data into zos
      val r = Some(baos.toByteArray)
      baos.reset()
      r
    } else None
  }
}
```

If all you need is compression, take a look at the `Enumeratee` instances provided in `play.filters.gzip.Gzip` and the `play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter` filter.

Comment: Yes, I need a zip archive (of several files). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only backpressure mechanism for `OutputStream` is blocking the thread. So one way or another, there will have to be a thread that is able to be blocked.

One way is to use piped streams.

```
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.io.PipedInputStream
import java.io.PipedOutputStream
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator
import scala.concurrent.ExecutorContext

def outputStream2(a: OutputStream => Unit, bufferSize: Int)
    (implicit ec1: ExecutionContext, ec2: ExecutionContext) = {
  val outputStream = new PipedOutputStream
  Future(a(outputStream))(ec1)
  val inputStream = new PipedInputStream(pipedOutputStream, bufferSize)
  Enumerator.fromStream(inputStream)(ec2)
}
```

Since the operations are blocking, you must take care to prevent deadlock.

Either use two different thread pools, or used a cached (unbounded) thread pool.